# Cycles image texture node is writen in python or c?

Tags: scripting

What language is the Cycles image texture node is written? are these editable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implemented in C, see:

The whole tree:
[tree/HEAD:/source/blender/nodes/shader/nodes](https://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender.git/tree/HEAD:/source/blender/nodes/shader/nodes)

The Mapping node:
[HEAD:/source/blender/nodes/shader/nodes/node_shader_mapping.c](https://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender.git/blob_plain/HEAD:/source/blender/nodes/shader/nodes/node_shader_mapping.c)
The image texture node:
[HEAD:/source/blender/nodes/shader/nodes/node_shader_tex_image.c](https://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender.git/blob_plain/HEAD:/source/blender/nodes/shader/nodes/node_shader_tex_image.c)

Editing / changing is possible, but then you embark on a journey of custom compiles whenever you want to update, maintaining your own branch might not be an option until you have a certain amount of C / compile / revision control experience.

Comment: BTW maybe OSL nodes are useful in this case